# Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'caputure<? extends IEntity>'to 'java.lang.Class<T>'

Tags: java

There are three class,class IEntity is an abstract class,which is only used for generic.

Class one:

```java
public abstract class IEntity {
}
```

class two:

```java
public class Config {
    private Class<? extends IEntity> clazz;

    public Class<? extends IEntity> getClazz(){
        return this.clazz;
    }
}
```

class three:

```java
public class EntityTest<T extends IEntity> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public void init(Config config){
       //Here is the wrong report
       // Failed to compile
        this.clazz=config.getClazz();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your entire code, it seems there is something more, e.g. the `Config` inizialitation. Post the `main` method

Comment: I think you need to use `Config<T>` in your init function

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not understood the difference between `<? extends IEntity>` and `<T extends IEntity>`.

Let's introduce two subclasses of `IEntity`, and a constructor for `Config` for a clearer explanation:

```
class Entity1 extends IEntity {}
class Entity2 extends IEntity {}

// in Config class
public Config(Class<? extends IEntity> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

At the line `this.clazz=config.getClazz();`, you are trying to assign a `Class<? extends IEntity>` to a `Class<T>`, where `T` is a subclass of `IEntity` or `IEntity` itself. The problem is, we don't know exactly what type of class `getClazz` returns. It could be `Class<Entity1>`, or `Class<Entity2>`. On the other hand, we *do* know what type we need - `Class<T>`. How can we make sure that whatever `getClazz` returns, is the same type of class as `Class<T>`? `T` could be `Entity2` but `getClazz` could return `Class<Entity1>`, couldn't it?

Here's a concrete example with code:

```
Config c = new Config(Entity1.class);
// c.config now contains Entity1.class
// the line below will attempt to assign an Entity1.class to a variable of type Class<Entity2>
new EntityTest<Entity2>().init(c);
```

You should now see why there is an error in `init`.

One way to make sure that `getClazz` returns the same type of class as `Class<T>` is to make `Config` generic too:

```
class Config<T extends IEntity> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public Class<T> getClazz(){
        return this.clazz;
    }
}

class EntityTest<T extends IEntity> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public void init(Config<T> config){
        this.clazz=config.getClazz();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this adds some explanation, still doesn't provide a solution.
Additionally, I fail to see the difference between <? extends IEntity> and <T extends IEntity>, either one should respect the same condition.

Comment: @Ralms The conversion is illegal, like trying to convert an `Animal` to a `Dog`. So the solution is to redesign the code to avoid this in the first place, but I without knowing what the OP is doing, I can't really say anything useful, can I? I can give not-useful solutions, such as changing the type of `clazz` or `config` to be the same as the other one, or add an unchecked cast and hope that it doesn't crash at some later point.

Comment: @Ralms Also, I'm pretty sure this Q&A isn't about the difference between `<? extends IEntity>` and `<T>` where `T` has a `IEntity` bound *in general*. It is about why you can't implicitly convert one to the other.

Answer (score 1):

`<? extend IEntity>` indicates that the class must be IEntity or it's subclass. The "T" in your code is just one subclass of IEntity(there can be many subclasses of `<? extend IEntity>`), you could not be sure that `<? extend IEntity>` is same as "T" or is subclass of "T" . so the type cast is illegale.